# How to validate a special character like ! in a password in Java without using regex?

Tags: java, validation, passwords

I'm new at Java, and my first assignment is building a password validator. I'm not sure if it's the operators or the way I set up the strings. I can't seem to get the validation right.  Also, how do I Validate special characters (!%$#...) without using regex.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Password {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
     
     final int MAX=12;
     final int MIN= 7;
     final int MIN_Uppercase=1;
     final int MIN_Lowercase=1;
     final String SPECIAL="!";
     
     int maxEl=0;
     int minEl=0;
     int upperCount=0;
     int lowerCount=0;
     String specialX = "!";
     
     
     
    // Print a message asking the user to input a password via the console 
        System.out.println("The password must contain:\r\n"
                + " At least one lowercase letter\r\n"
                + " At least one uppercase letter\r\n"
                + " At least minimum 7 characters\r\n"
                + " At least maximum 12 characters\r\n"
                + " An exclamation point: !"
                + "Please enter a password: ");
        
    //Receive the input via the console
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String password = scan.nextLine();
        int passwordLen = password.length();
        
        
    //Check if there is at least one lower case letter  
    for (int i = 0; i < passwordLen; i++ ) {
        char chr = password.charAt(i);
        
        //Check if there is at least one upper case letter
        
        if (Character.isUpperCase(chr))
            upperCount++;
        
        //Check if there is at least one lower case letter  
        else if (Character.isLowerCase(chr))
            lowerCount++;
        
        //Check if there are no more than 12 characters
        else if (Character.isDigit(chr))
            maxEl++;
        
        //Check if there are at least 7 characters
        else if (Character.isDigit(chr))
            minEl++;        
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    //If the password is valid, print "Password valid and accepted"
    if(upperCount < MIN_Uppercase
        && lowerCount < MIN_Lowercase
        && maxEl < MAX
        && minEl < MIN
        && specialX !="!")
        System.out.println("Password valid and\r\n"+ "accepted");
    
    // If the password isn’t valid, print "Error"
    else {
        System.out.println("Error!  ");
            
            
            
    } 
    
    
    
    
    

}
```

}

Comment: `String#contains` would be my starting point.  I'd have the special characters in array, which you could easily loop over

Comment: As there's only one special character `!`, what about adding another `else` to your existing if/else statement?

Comment: Also are you sure your checks of password length work?

Comment: @tgdavies When I tried that, I kept getting errors. Can you show me an example?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I honestly don't understand, I just started with Java 3 days ago.

Comment: @tgdavies yeah, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Show the code you added to check for the `!` and the error you were getting.

Comment: I know it's not right but

Comment: Sorry, not used to this platform.          final String SPECIAL="!";     String specialX = "!";      specialX == SPECIAL  It's passing passwords without the exclamation mark.

Comment: Add details as edits to the Qirstion, nor Comments.

Comment: `password.charAt(i) == '!'`?

Comment: Honestly, I decided to go with regex.