# Java Password Validated Without Regex

Tags: java, validation

I am very new to Java and have been working on the exercise for days now. The goal of this exercise is to validate a password without using regex.

The requirements of this exercise is:
Via the console, ask the user to create a password with the following requirements.
The password must contain:
○ At least one lowercase letter
○ At least one uppercase letter
***○ At least minimum 7 characters
○ At least maximum 12 characters***
***○ An exclamation point: !***
● If the user meets all the requirements, print the string "Password valid and
accepted" to the console
● If the password fails any of the requirements, print the string "Error ".

My issue is that I can not get set the Max and Min length for the password requirement to 7 - min & 12 Max. I am also having trouble adding "!" as a password requirement. Can someone please direct me in the correct direction?

```
Via the console, ask the user to create a password with the following requirements.
```

The password must contain:
○ At least one lowercase letter
○ At least one uppercase letter
○ At least minimum 7 characters
○ At least maximum 12 characters
○ An exclamation point: !
● If the user meets all the requirements, print the string "Password valid and
accepted" to the console
● If the password fails any of the requirements, print the string "Error ".

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WhatToEat {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*
         * At Least One Lower case
         * At Least one Upper case
         * At least 7 Characters minimum 
         * At least 12 characters maximum
         * Exclamation mark required
         */
        
        final int MIN_LENGTH = 7;
        final int MAX_LENGTH = 12;
        final int NUM_UPPER_LETTERS = 1;
        final int NUM_LOWER_LETTERS = 1;
        final int NUM_DIGITS =0;
        int minLength = 0;
        int maxLength = 0;
        int upperCount = 0;
        int lowerCount = 0;
        int digitCount = 0;
        
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("Enter Password Here:");
            String input = in.nextLine();
            int inputLen = input.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < inputLen; i++) {
                char ch = input.charAt(i);
                if (Character.isUpperCase(ch))
                    upperCount++;
                else if (Character.isLowerCase(ch))
                    lowerCount++;
                else if (Character.isDigit(ch))
                    digitCount++;   
                else if (Character.isDigit(ch))
                    minLength++;
                else if (Character.isDigit(ch))
                    maxLength++;
            }
        }
        if(upperCount <= NUM_UPPER_LETTERS 
                && lowerCount <= NUM_LOWER_LETTERS 
                && digitCount <= NUM_DIGITS 
                && minLength <= MIN_LENGTH
                && maxLength <= MAX_LENGTH)
            System.out.println("Password valid and accepted");
        else {
            System.out.println("Error");
```

Comment: Inside your `for` loop, you could have a condition like `if (ch == '!')`

Comment: The requirements say "characters", but you are checking for "digits" (isDigit)

Comment: @EdsonPassos I am not understanding what you mean by that, can you clarify plz

Comment: What do you think `else if (Character.isDigit(ch)) minLength++;` does? What do you expect the value of `minLength` to be at the end of the for loop?

Comment: This person is making the same odd mistake... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71366037/how-to-validate-a-special-character-like-in-a-password-in-java-without-using-r

Comment: @tgdavies I was thinking that it would set the minimum length requirement which is 7. I now know that is incorrect, So I am looking for direction on trying to find the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

this last IF-Else part need little modification as the following:
i added "!" check and also regarding the min and max it should be compared with the password string length to check if the pasword in the range or not as i did
and you should remove the last two Else-IF

```
    if(upperCount <= NUM_UPPER_LETTERS 
            && lowerCount <= NUM_LOWER_LETTERS 
            && digitCount <= NUM_DIGITS 
            && inputLen >= MIN_LENGTH
            && inputLen <= MAX_LENGTH
            && input.contains("!"))
        System.out.println("Password valid and accepted");
    else {
        System.out.println("Error");
```

Comment: you welcome and if this helped you don't forget to accept it ;)

Answer (score 0):

you should also change this

```
   if(upperCount <= NUM_UPPER_LETTERS 
            && lowerCount <= NUM_LOWER_LETTERS 
            && digitCount <= NUM_DIGITS 
            && minLength <= MIN_LENGTH
            && maxLength <= MAX_LENGTH)
    System.out.println("Password valid and accepted");
```

to

```
 if(upperCount <= NUM_UPPER_LETTERS 
            && lowerCount >= NUM_LOWER_LETTERS 
            && minLength >= MIN_LENGTH
            && maxLength <= MAX_LENGTH)

    System.out.println("Password valid and accepted");
```

As you want your lowerCount and minLength to be above the minimum number and only the maxLength and upperCount to be below the hard limits you have.
I'm not sure about this condition as you didn't mention the minimum number of digits you need "&& digitCount >= NUM_DIGITS", but worth considering that as well.